# Ruby on Rails - Users following relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating my first Rails app and I want a very basic user system (no validation considerations happening yet) where one user can follow another similar to Twitter or Instagram.

After search stackoverflow previously, I found the following video on YouTube and tried to follow their instructions before proceeding.  I've linked it below as a reference.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSUWu50XK48

I wrote the following classes, and also wrote the following migration to add these to my database as well.  Although the migration was not found in the video, I think part of my problem may be with the migration class as well.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password

    has_many :posts
    has_many :followers, through: :followings
end

class Following < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :follower, class_name: 'User'
end

class CreateFollowings < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :followings do |t|
            t.integer       :user_id
            t.integer       :follower_id
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

After running `rake db:drop db:migrate`, my database filled out the tables as I expected, however I also tried to then run `rake db:seed` after writing the following in my `seeds.rb` file.

```
jerry = User.create( :name => "jerry", :email => "jerry@seinfeld.com", :password => "newman" )
george = User.create( :name => "george", :email => "george@costanza.com", :password => "bosco" )
elaine = User.create( :name => "elaine", :email => "elaine@benes.com", :password => "dance" )
kramer = User.create( :name => "kramer", :email => "cozmo@kramer.com", :password => "bagels" )

kramer.following.create(follower: jerry)
```

I tried both pluralizing `following` and `followings` in that last `.create()` method, but both times the error in my console was "NoMethodError: undefined method 'following'.

If anyone may be able to offer assistance here, I'd be grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the following:

- `has_many :followings` in the `User` class.

Class definitions:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :followings
  has_many :followers, through: :followings
  ...
end

class class Following < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: 'User'
end
```

After running the migration to create the `followings` table, you should be able to do the following from the console:

```
> jerry = User.create( :name => "jerry", :email => "jerry@seinfeld.com", :password => "newman" )
> george = User.create( :name => "george", :email => "george@costanza.com", :password => "bosco" )
> elaine = User.create( :name => "elaine", :email => "elaine@benes.com", :password => "dance" )
> kramer = User.create( :name => "kramer", :email => "cozmo@kramer.com", :password => "bagels" )

> kramer.followers
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
> kramer.followers.count
=> 0
> kramer.followers << george

> kramer.followers.count
=> 1
> kramer.followers.map(&:name)
> ["george"]
```

Comment: Oh you're completely correct, I did forget the `has_many :followings` in the `User` model.  I am curious about the second part, the migration for the `users` table.  Why does the user table need a `follower_id`.  Shouldn't it have many followers, which is why a join table in the database was made?

Comment: You are right; it does not require the `follower_id` field in the users table. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I've also changed my seeds file to be `kramer.followings.create(user: jerry)` which allowed the entry to be made in the database.